# issue with cv::warpPerspective() function

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I want to superimpose an image on a previously detected item using haarcascade classifiers by using warpPerspective. The image seems properly scaled but the rest of the image becomes black.

I have tried to modify transparency of source and destination image but I do not know if it was successful.

[image without warpPerspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTzjl.png)

[image with warpPerspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCl7l.png)

```
Rect r = boundingRects.carRects.at(i).rect; // points of the object in the image.
vector<Point2d> imagePoints;
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(r.x, r.y));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(r.x + r.width, r.y));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(r.x + r.width, r.y+ r.height));
imagePoints.push_back(Point2d(r.x, r.y + r.height));

dimensions.push_back(Point2d(0, 0)); // dimensions of the source image
dimensions.push_back(Point2d(899, 0));
dimensions.push_back(Point2d(899, 539));
dimensions.push_back(Point2d(0, 539));

H = findHomography(carAlertObject.dimensions, imagePoints); // get homography matrix
warpPerspective(carAlertObject.img, img, H,img.size()); // carAlertObject contains the source image and dimensions, img is the destination image
```

Comment: can you add the images?

Comment: I have added images with and without using warpPerspective().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to use a mask image to apply warpPerspective function and then do the sum of that image and destination image to have a correct result.